# Outsource @functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

*I'm using ASP.NET with Razor as my view-engine.*

There are **different .cshtml files**, but **each of them contains** the following code:

```
@functions
{
    // Here some of my code, but it's the same code for each .cshtml file...
}
```

My question is: How can I outsource this `@functions` to an external file? *Because at the moment I have the same code in all the files and I don't like that.*

Comment: Use partial view common to all view having common functions...

Comment: This was the term I was looking for, found this usefull link, thanks a lot: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/partial-view-in-mvc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Partial View" was the term I was looking for.

Thanks a lot to [Pranav Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704008/pranav-singh) for his helpfull comment.

**Tutorial:**

Partial View allows us to put HTML and C# code into a file that we can reuse across multiple other views. This is very useful when you work on a large application.

Assume we have the following peice of code that we would like to make reusable for other views.

[image]

We will extract the above marked code and paste it in a new "partial view" and then we'll just call that "partial view" from this foreach loop. Please use the following.

**Step 1**

Select the above code and copy it to the clipboard.

**Step 2**

Right-click on any view folder to create a new "partial view".

[image]

You can use any name for this view page but the underscore sign (_) is recommended to be used before the view name that represents something that is reusable. You also have the opportunity to select the "Model class" in the above dialog to create a strongly typed view. And remember to check the checkbox "Create as a partial view".

**Step 3**

Now, in the "partial view" page paste all the code you copied above. You may need to fix some errors here like @item.Name will become @Model.Name. Here is the complete code:

[image]

**Step 4**

One more thing, you need to place a reference at the location from where we copied the code, here you go:

[image]

Remember to pass the "partial view" name and model name. Now, run the application, your application will work the same because we just set up a new structure in the application.

Hope this helps.

> All credits goes to [Abhimanyu K Vatsa](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/authors/abhikumarvatsa/abhimanyu-k-vatsa.aspx), this tutorial was found [HERE](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/partial-view-in-mvc/).